# sql query shows every result 3 times and not only once

Tags: php, mysql

I got a sql table containing a string that i need to join in another table. 
First i got the string from the SQL table:

```
$sql = "Select coupons.restrict_to_products From coupons Where coupons.coupon_id = 2";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
$array2=implode(",", $row);
```

So if I now echo `$array2`it shows me "42, 43, 73" which is what i needed. Now i am trying to join another table with the result like this:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT products_name FROM products_description WHERE products_id IN ($array2)");
while ($row2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    $array3=implode(",", $row2);
    echo $array3."<br>";
}
```

The code works but for some reason it shows me every productname 3 times and not only once. The result of the `echo` is:

```
Productname 1
Productname 1
Productname 1
Productname 2
Productname 2
Productname 2
Productname 3
Productname 3
Productname 3
```

What am I missing?

Comment: use distinct at product name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `group by`

```
group by Productname
```

or you can try `distinct`

Comment: may be duplicate data available in your table

Comment: if my answer helps you please accept my answer :) @MarcelW

Answer (score 1):

The *coupons* might have applied to *same products* so it is returning `3` times the same product. Try to `group` the products by `id` which would be unique. Try -

```
SELECT products_name 
FROM products_description 
WHERE products_id IN ($array2) 
GROUP BY products_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT(products_name) FROM products_description WHERE products_id IN ($array2) ");
while ($row2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    $array3=implode(",", $row2);
    echo $array3."<br>";
}
```

OR

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT products_name FROM products_description WHERE products_id IN ($array2) group by products_id ");
```

Answer (score 0):

Or if the rows aren't duplicate, you can grab all the names associated with those ids

```
SELECT products_id,GROUP_CONCAT(products_name) AS products_names
FROM products_description
WHERE products_id IN ($array)
GROUP BY products_id
```